# Not able to login through GUI in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, login, lightdm, authentication

I'm unable to login through GUI. On typing the correct password, I get a black screen and back to login screen. However, when tried with tty1 I was logged in. Then I tried reinstalling `lightdm` and `xorg` packages, but in vain. 
These are the contents of my `xsession-errors`

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 1: /etc/profile: id: not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 12: [: Illegal number:
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 36: /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: xrdb: not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 1: /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: ls: not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 98: exec: gnome-session: not found
```

How do I overcome this issue?

**UPDATE 1:** Image of my /etc/profile
[image]

Comment: There is no need to add pictures. Add the results as they are in terminal. Copy-paste them here inside code sample. We will need additional info in order to locate the problem. `cat /usr/sbin/lightdm-session; cat /etc/lighdm/lightdm.conf; cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Answer (score 2):

The following lines (taken from `/etc/profile` on my Debian box) seem to be what you're missing:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

add them after the first two lines (the comments) and retry your log in.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the same problem I had on 13.10, only I had to add /sbin to the user path (else clause).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a syntax error in your /etc/profile file - probably somewhere around this fragment

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PS1='# '
else
```

Likely all the other errors are due to lightdm's environment not being properly set as a result of that (in particular, its PATH variable - so that the executables like 'ls' are not found)

If so, then try opening /etc/profile in the TTY virtual terminal using a command-line editor e.g.

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

and fixing the syntax

Comment: steeldriver, I tried to analyze /etc/profile, but could not find out what is wrong. I've added image of my profile file. Please check the update. Thanks.

Comment: OK so it looks like I was wrong - I don't see anything wrong with your /etc/profile. It's possible that the /usr/sbin/lightdm-session script is the problem but that should have been replaced by reinstalling the lightdm package, I think. Sorry - I don't have any more ideas right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, running 13.04. The error message "id: not found" made me think that some change or installation I did somehow does not make the command "id" available. I changed the line
**if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then**
to
**if [ "`/usr/bin/id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then**
Using the full path to **id** solved the problem for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Where did you the change? Please answer (if you want to help) more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

maybe add a line to the top `echo $PATH` to see if your path variable is being set up correctly. If it is not you may want to add a line `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` <-- that is my default path from ubuntu. This also keeps everything from your original path and adds onto it. It's weird that this would happen though...